# dplyr: add jitter to repeated values within a group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some numeric data (`value`) that is grouped (by `Tissue`). I'd like to add a small jitter to the values that occur more than once within each group.

Input:

```
df <- structure(list(value = c(1.05155243861439, 
1.05155243861439, 1.05155243861439, 11.9769249796958, 1.05155243861439, 
1.05155243861439, 1.05155243861439, 1.05155243861439, 1.05155243861439
), Tissue = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("Brain", "Marrow", "Spleen", "Testes", "Vis"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("value", 
"Tissue"), row.names = c("SM-2", "SM-3", "SM-4", "SM-5", 
"SM-6", "SM-7", "SM-8", "SM-9", "SM-10"), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried using  `group_by` and `mutate`, but this adds the same jitter to each repeated element per group (kind of pointless, right?).

```
df <- df %>%
    group_by(Tissue, value) %>%
    mutate(jitter = ifelse(n()>1, value+runif(1, min=-0.15, max=0.15), value))
```

Output:

```
Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
Groups: Tissue, value [4]

      value Tissue     jitter
      (dbl) (fctr)      (dbl)
1  1.051552    Vis  1.1793382
2  1.051552    Vis  1.1793382
3  1.051552    Vis  1.1793382
4 11.976925 Testes 11.9769250
5  1.051552    Vis  1.1793382
6  1.051552 Spleen  1.0515524
7  1.051552    Vis  1.1793382
8  1.051552  Brain  0.9284923
9  1.051552  Brain  0.9284923
```

The 4th and 6th rows are correctly unjittered. But rows `[1-3,5,7]` I'd like to have unique jitters. Any ideas from people that are better at `dplyr`? :(

Comment: Instead of `runif(1, ...)` add `runif(n(), ...)`.

Comment: @Gregor that still shouldn't work cause they are grouping by both `Tissue` and `value` for some reason. Though when grouping only by `Tissue` it won't work because the condition is of length 1 and hence, `ifelse` will always return a result of length 1. One of many reasons why `ifelse` sucks in general.

Comment: I will retain the last sentence :)

Comment: Ah, of course. In that case I would recommend `jitter = value + runif(n(), min=-0.15, max=0.15) * (n() > 1)`

Comment: So general rule of thumb, better to avoid `ifelse`? Is a vector of logicals like the accepted answer a better approach?

Comment: It's definitely faster. There's nothing wrong with `ifelse` when it works (tautologically true, I suppose), but it's easy to slip into the habit of using it and not realize why it's not working. See my edited answer for an `if()` version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, `ifelse()` is problematic in this case because the length of what it returns must be the same as the length of the test. Since your test is length 1, `ifelse` won't return random numbers of length `n()`.

We can get around this by multiplying the jittered values by a logical of whether or not `n() > 1`. If false, it will multiply by 0; if true, by 1.

```
df %>%
    group_by(Tissue, value) %>%
    mutate(
        jitter = value + runif(n(), min = -0.15, max = 0.15) * (n() > 1)
    )
#       value Tissue     jitter
#       (dbl) (fctr)      (dbl)
# 1  1.051552    Vis  1.1020925
# 2  1.051552    Vis  1.1398244
# 3  1.051552    Vis  0.9339355
# 4 11.976925 Testes 11.9769250
# 5  1.051552    Vis  1.1186657
# 6  1.051552 Spleen  1.0515524
# 7  1.051552    Vis  1.0249348
# 8  1.051552  Brain  1.0814222
# 9  1.051552  Brain  1.0496148
```

With a single condition, you could actually use plain of `if(){} else`, this would also work inside `mutate`:

```
jitter = value + if(n() > 1) {runif(n(), -.15, .15)} else 0
```

Which you prefer is up to you.

Comment: I should note that I'm an idiot and asked to jitter the wrong column. I was actually looking for `jitter = as.numeric(Tissue) + runif(n(), min = -0.15, max = 0.15) * (n() > 1)`.

Comment: you could replace the bit `runif(n(), min = -0.15, max = 0.15)` with `jitter(0 * value, amount=0.15)` (but it's arguably harder to understand what's going on)